# Determine of the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space with usual addition and scalar multiplcation as follows: $r[x,y]=[ry,rx]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

$\require{amssymb}$
Determine of the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space with usual addition and scalar multiplication as follows: $r[x,y]=[ry,rx]$

One of my axioms says that **if $1$ is the multiplication identity in $F$ , then $1\bigotimes v = v$**

Clearly in this case, if we let $v=[2,3]$, then $1\bigotimes [2,3]=[3,2]\neq v$, but is this the right axiom to use?

I don't understand what they mean by "if 1 is the multiplication identity". What does this mean exactly?

Is this the same as multiplicative inverse?

Comment: it means "if we indicate by $1$ the multiplicative group indentity of $F^*$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is in other terms the action of the field on the underlying abelian group $G$. By field action, it is meant a ring homomorphism on $F$ to the ring of abelian group endomorphisms $\operatorname{End}{G}$, usually called "multiplication of a given scalar by a vector"
$$F\to\operatorname{End}{G}$$

Among other thing it must be that under this field homomorphism the multiplicative identity $1$ of $F$ is mapped to the identity endomorphism $\mathbf{1}_G$:
$$1\mapsto \mathbf{1}_G$$

The case you presented does not satisfy this constraint, so it is not a vector space.